# Qt-webkit WebSocket protocol

Tags: qt, websocket, qtwebkit

Which WebSocket protocol is supported by Qt-webkit?
For example, the following list has the WebSocket protocol lists.

[The WebSocket protocol: draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright After some research I could find some details on this but I need some confirmation on this.

As for qt 4.7 there are non.

And for Qt 4.8 following mails provide some idea but again need to be confirmed.

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2011-June/017102.html.

also the comments of the following bug report might help you as well
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50099